# gawk nextfile with compressed input

Tags: bash, gzip, gawk

I'm trying to use awk's nextfile statement with **multiple gzipped input files**.

I've googled for this before posting but it looks like I'm the only one who want to do this :D

This is what i need to do:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
print "start",strftime();
}
/match/{
print FILENAME,"->",$0
count++
nextfile
}
END{
print count
print "stop",strftime();
}
' /var/log/*.2015-01-23.gz
```

Suddenly awk can't read by itself gzipped files, so I have to use zcat and I've modified my syntax as follow:

```
zcat /var/log/*.2015-01-23.gz | awk '
BEGIN{
print "start",strftime();
}
/match/{
print FILENAME,"->",$0
count++
nextfile
}
END{
print count
print "stop",strftime();
}
'
```

But this way nextfile statement won't work because awk see just one input data flow.

My awk version:

```
# awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

Note: what exposed is a resume of what I need to do in the **END** action, so don't propose to use zgrep or something else. I need awk.

Note2: Files will be elaborated togheter.

Thanks

Comment: "Suddenly"? When was awk able to work with gzipped files?

Comment: @glenn: unfortunately sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the files one by one, hold the Name of the file in a shell variable and print this in awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
for LOGFILE in /var/log/*.2015-01-23.gz
do
    zcat "$LOGFILE" |
    awk '
        BEGIN{
            print "start",strftime();
        }
        /match/{
            print "'$LOGFILE'","->",$0
            last
        }
        END{
            print "stop",strftime();
        }
    '
done
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to do it. There will be a slight degradation in performance (from having to invoke zcat and awk multiple times) but compared to the file i/o and the decompression I can't imagine it will be noticeable.

Comment: This is not the solution because the BEGIN and END actions are executed n times for every input files. I need to do a complessive elaboration.
I'm modifying the sample code to represent this.
Also, there is no _last_ in awk